# Manipulating JSON data sets

Tags: javascript, json, dataset

So I have an array `myarr[]` of JSON objects in the form: `{ "a":"", "b":"" }`

Are there efficient methods for getting an array of b:

`[ myarr[0].b, myarr[1].b, myarr[2].b, ... ]`

Or do I have to manually iterate through the `myarr` to build the array of b?

Comment: You will have to iterate the array, yes, but there are helper functions that can simplify the usage.

Comment: @Bergi What would those helpers be?

Comment: @dlackey: [pluck](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) for example as suggested (and re-implemented) in the answers.

Comment: @Bergi - Ah, thanks.  I hand't heard of "pluck" and thought it was the name of am abstract value like people use "foo" and "bar".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not have fun with prototypes and extend Array to obtain a handy and reusable function:

```
Array.prototype.pluck = function(key) {
    var i = this.length, 
        plucked = [];
    while(i --) {
        plucked[i] = this[i][key] || ""
    }

    return plucked;
}
```

With this one, you can do:

```
collection.pluck(keyName)
```

To get back your desired result. Check here for a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jYrNN/1/

Comment: Why the `|| ""`? Just let the result be `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) library.

I'd suggest checking out the implementation for [pluck](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L236).

What you'd want to do is effectively: `_.pluck(myarr, 'b')`

Answer (score 1):

```
var b_arr = $.map(myarr, function(val, i) { return val.b; });
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8dnna/)

or wihtout jQuery

```
var b_arr = myarr.map(function(val) { return val.b })
                 .filter(function(n){return n || false});
```

Comment: OP doesn't use jQuery, so the native method might be more appropriate

Answer (score -1):

jQuery does provide api to parse json

```
$.each(myarr, function(key,value)
  {
    alert(key);
    alert(value);
  });
```

Comment: Neither does he need to parse JSON, nor do you use that method.